# Using htpasswd with PHP on IIS

Tags: php, iis, .htpasswd

I'm using an IIS 10 on Windows Server 2019 with PHP 7.3.
IIS is working great with .htaccess but .htpasswd is not working.

1. Is .htpasswd not supported but .htaccess is supported?
2. Has basic auth be done with local users?

Comment: I don't think IIS support `.htaccess` at all. That's why there are tutorial on [how to convert .htaccess to web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig). Do you have a separated `web.config` for IIS?

Comment: .htpasswd  was not supported in IIS 7 version, but newer versions are supported

Comment: If you need .htpasswd support, you may implement authentication with a [htpasswd-parser](https://github.com/Amhr/htpasswd-parser) and [some php magic](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).

Comment: .htaccess is supported with IIS10, as my RewriteCond are working. I'm wondering that htpasswd is not working, but .htaccess is working